# Let $k\geq2$ and $l\in\mathbb{N}$. Prove that $(k+1)^l > k^l$.

Tags: inequality

As a part of another proof, I need to prove that $(k+1)^l > k^l$, for all $k$, with $k\geq2$ and $l\in\mathbb{N}$. I need some help starting the proof. Thank you.

Comment: Do you know the binomial theorem?

Comment: What have you tried? There are several methods to show this, but hopefully it makes sense intuitively first.

Comment: Where do you see a problem? Is it not obvious? Just $k+1>k$.

Comment: The left-hand side of your inequality is $k^l$ plus other terms that are positive. See the hint by Jack Pfaffinger.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
Since $l\in\mathbb{N}$, by binomial theorem, $$(k+1)^l = k^l + (whatever) + 1^l$$, and now try to proof that $(whatever)\geq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Do it by induction on $l$.

For the case $l = 1$, we have that $$(k+1)^1=k+1>k=k^1.$$

Suppose $(k+1)^{l} > k^l,$ then $$(k+1)^{l+1}=(k+1)(k+1)^l > (k+1)k^l = k^{l+1}+k^l > k^{l+1}.$$

Try to figure out where the hypothesis on $k$ has been used. Notice also that we started from $l=1$, since it does not hold for $l=0.$

Answer (score 0):

By a telescoping argument, 
$$(k+1)^l - k^l = ((k+1)-k)\sum_{i=0}^{l-1}(k+1)^{(l-1)-i}k^i$$
which is clearly positive.

Answer (score 0):

A counting argument could do it:

$k^l$ counts the number of words of length $l$ that can be formed from an alphabet of $k$ letters. Now what happens if we add a new letter to the alphabet?

Answer (score 0):

Another way to see this is to take $l$th roots. Then all you want to prove is that $$k+1>k,$$ which is clearly true.

Comment: But now you have to prove that taking $l$th roots preserves the inequality, which seems equally hard to the original problem...

Comment: @BallBoy This is just a heuristic. Move in reverse direction.

Comment: The reverse direction yields a mere restatement of the question

Comment: @BallBoy Nope. Don't be silly. If $a>b>0,$ then $a^n>b^n$ for positive integers $n.$

Comment: But that's the hard part of the fact we're trying to prove! You should include your proof of that fact in your answer

Comment: @BallBoy No. Because that's easy, and is assumed. Show that $a>b>0$ implies $a^2>ab$ and $ab>b^2,$ from which the result follows. Then induct. You're bothering me over trivialities!

Comment: Is that so much easier than the statement to prove? To me it seems _harder_ because it's more general, but only the OP would know, I suppose. They're both triviliaties -- the entire question is about trivialities :)

Comment: If your main ingredients are $k+1>k$ and induction, your answer is similar to @RiccardoAllegrone's, but you mix your ingredients in a nicer way